# catkin messages and node in same package

Tags: catkin, nodes, services, messages, library

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

While working on some ROS node we bumped into the following problem:

We got a package containing a library, messages and services, the library is using these messages and services

The header files of the services and messages are generated succesfully, however when building the library, the error occurs that the header files of the messages and services are not found.

Is this due to the fact that services and messages should not be in a same packages as library or node?

the error looks like

```
header.h:34:27: fatal error: ns/header.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

Thank in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53265/catkin-messages-and-node-in-same-package/) by [Dickvdsteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3933/dickvdsteen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2013-01-24

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dickvdsteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3933/dickvdsteen/) on 2013-01-24**:
@KruseT, thanks for your answer, i inspected the cmake and i dont think its a typo

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-01-24**:
Please provide the exact error message, failing code snippets and cmake files.

**Comment by [Dickvdsteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3933/dickvdsteen/) on 2013-01-24**:
I noticed that the messages and services are generated after the library builds, for that reason it cant be found. However i call generate_messages before add_executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, messages and services may lie in the same package as other code, though it is usually a good practice to put them into separate packages, to make the definitions reusable without the other code.

See the tutorial here, where messages and code are mixed:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29

So you may have made a typo somewhere in your package or message names instead.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Avio](https://answers.ros.org/users/19863/avio/) on 2018-06-12**:
I was having a similar issue, the message generation part may be quite tricky and requires some care. Please also refer to [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/73048/first-compile-with-messages-messages-not-found/?answer=73063#post-id-73063) and its links for more tips about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved it!

Seems the following line was needed after calling add library

```
add_dependencies(lib lib_gencpp)
```

is this the right way to do it or not?

---

Originally posted by [Dickvdsteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3933/dickvdsteen/) with karma: 103 on 2013-01-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-01-24**:
This would be a bug, at least in the documentation. Is it possible for you to post the full CMakeLists.txt, so that we may reproduce?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-01-24**:
The dependency is perfectly right assuming that your project is called "lib".If you build code which depends on generated C++ headers (which is usually the case) you need to tell CMake about that dependency else it may try to build the library before generating the headers for the messages.

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-01-26**:
Note that lib is a very bad name for a project or library. Choose library names which are prefixedwith your project names, and choose meaningful project names.

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-01-26**:
Also see https://github.com/ros/genmsg/issues/20